# Xamarin Stepper increment on Entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, stepper

I want to have a stepper to increase/decrease the value in an Entry. I referenced to other posts online but my increment does not work. Do I need to have a code behind for the values to increase in Entry?

**xaml**

```
 <Entry BindingContext="{x:Reference stepper}" Text="1" />


 <Stepper x:Name="stepper" Minimum="1" Maximum="4" Increment="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bind the Entry's `Text` property to the Stepper's `value` property

```
<Entry BindingContext="{x:Reference stepper}" Text="{Binding Value}" />


<Stepper x:Name="stepper" Minimum="1" Maximum="4" Increment="1"/>
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much it works! Can I ask if I want to get the value from entry after the increment, do I access it by using entry.Text in code too?

Comment: yes, or you could bind both controls to the same VM property

Answer (score 0):

do you need write the value of stepper on the entry? if that right then you need create a binding value, because yo need "listening" when the value change and put this value on the entry.

[here there is an explain for this.](http://%20https://medium.com/makingtuenti/mvvm-base-c-sharp-10d818871595)

Comment: The entry will have another value bound to it from the start and I want the stepper to increase/decrease the value. I can't open the link